# Why do I get an error running Catchment Polygon Processing?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, terrain, watershed, catchment

I am trying to run catchment polygon processing in ArcGIS 10.3, and this is what i get "error hresult e_fail has been returned from a call to a com component" 
Can you help me to debug this error?

Comment: Welcome to GIS.SE! Please include the software and version you are using as well as the steps you have taken that lead to this error.

Comment: @Kersten.  Arcgis 10.3, I covered all steps required for stream delineation, was now delineating the watershed, was just on the very first steps. i did catchment grid, so catchment polygon processing was the next step.